# css grid layout auto adjust column and rows

Tags: javascript, css, less, scss-mixins

I am creating a grid with a dynamic content. I want to adjust the column like. if the column height is less then put two, three column in one column. If the column height is more then put one column.

[image]

I want column3 go under coulmn2 and column4 go to column3 position and so everything adjust according to the content

```css
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Less than what? Then put two? More than what? I don't get it

Comment: mean everything should adjust according to the maximum column height. if the height of two column is equal to one (highest) column. then put two column in one column.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

then create Masonry [Masonry Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout)

Comment: can you provide masonry layout for such scenario.  grid-template-rows: masonry; is not accepting